# Subversion Ignore Certain Files

Tags: svn

I realise there are a few million pages describing ignoring files and folders in SVN. I am despite the vast amount of information slowly going insane trying to get this correct.

I need to ideally create a txt file that can contains the list of ignored files and folders. This can then be svn'd so that it is carried into each new checkout.

To create a file so far I have the following:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

If I have say the following structure:

```
folder1
      folder2
             folder3
folder4
       test.php
```

I need to effectively ignore anything in folder3 but include folder3 itself.

I need to ignore test.php specifically from folder4 but include folder4 and any other files/folders generated

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe u starting from reading bukz http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html and describe yo problemz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nor

```
>svn pl -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
    Folder4\test.php
    Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\*.*
```

nor

```
>svn pl -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
    Folder4/test.php
    Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/*
```

thus: you can't operate with single file and tree-pattern in it
will not work:

```
>svn st
 M      .
?       Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\a.txt
?       Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\b.txt
?       Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\test.php
?       Folder1\Folder2\test.php
?       Folder4\Folder5\test.php
?       Folder4\a.txt
?       Folder4\b.txt
?       Folder4\test.php
```

You have to add [ignore patterns](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) to the parents of ignored objects

```
>svn pl -v -R
Properties on 'Folder1\Folder2\Folder3':
  svn:ignore
    *.*

Properties on 'Folder4':
  svn:ignore
    test.php
```

in order to get needed results

```
>svn st --no-ignore
 M      Folder1\Folder2\Folder3
I       Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\a.txt
I       Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\b.txt
I       Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\test.php
?       Folder1\Folder2\test.php
 M      Folder4
?       Folder4\Folder5\test.php
?       Folder4\a.txt
?       Folder4\b.txt
I       Folder4\test.php
```

Comment: So effectively there is no way to have a global file to ignore in SVN, in order to ignore contents of a directory I would need to place a .svnignore file into the folder ie folder3. I also read that if in the root I say ignore bin, then every instance of bin would be ignored, presumably I would have to do the same thing where I place a .svnignore file in bins parent directory so only this particular directory is affected.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat - you can (to *some extend*) have such file, but it will require a) special processing b) generating more than single ignore-property

Comment: @TheHumbleRat - You shouldn't need .svnignore files.  Subversion's `svn:ignore` metadata property should be all that you need.  These properties are part of the repository, so they'll exist on every checkout.

Comment: Many thanks @bta and Lazy Badger, it certainly makes much more sense now. Thank you both for taking the time to respond.